# Magento add position 999 when assign product to category

Tags: php, sorting, magento, magento-1.9, natural-sort

I'm using Magento 1.9.x and trying to change default position number of products.

Ex, when we assign product to category via product page i need to set it to 999 position

[image]

I changed default **position** field value of **catalog_category_product** table

[image]

But nothing changed.

i changed `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category.php`

```
/**
         * Add products to category
         */
        if (!empty($insert)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($insert as $productId => $position) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => (int)$id,
                    'product_id'  => (int)$productId,
                    'position'    =>  (int)$position ? (int)$position : 999
                );
            }
            //(int)$position
            $adapter->insertMultiple($this->_categoryProductTable, $data);
        }
```

but it only effect when adding products to category via category page.

anyone know a solution for this please, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to apply a change after saving a product you may observe the event "catalog_product_save_after". In the method body you can simply set your desired position via custom sql query.

PS. Always consider to use an event observer or local class rewrite instead of editing the core.